# Get ID of dom-element

Tags: javascript

`console.log(video);`

puts in my console the following line:

```
<object type=​"application/​x-shockwave-flash" class=​"video" data=​"http:​/​/​www.youtube.com/​v/​vyFAF-J3jzM" width=​"308" height=​"100" id=​"video" style=​"visibility:​ visible;​ ">​…​</object>
```

So "video" holds the entire dom-object. How can I query the ID of this object with JavaScript?

Something like `var vidID = video.getId();`

Comment: m1nus one for use of unprofessional language

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
var videoElement = document.getElementById('video');
var idOfElement = videoElement.getAttribute('id');
```

Comment: No real need to use `.getAttribute()`, according to this test, it's 50% slower than `.id` - http://jsperf.com/getattribute-vs-id

Comment: The real question is rather does smth.id works on all the navigators.  Sure smth.getAttribute does...

Comment: @MUYBelgium Who is smith and where is he navigating to?

Comment: This is the top google result for "Javascript get id" and I was looking for "getElementById" because I'm rusty... +1

Comment: "smth" is "something"; "navigator" is "browser".

Answer (score 69):

It's simply `video.id` ........

Comment: Be careful, using `element.id` on a form can also return its child element with name of `id`, see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0tjrLx4u/)

Comment: So better to use `element.getAttribute('id')`

Answer (score 12):

How about…

```
var vidID = video.id;
```

…?